# How to implement heartbeat signal for servlets for finding if the connection is active between server and client

Tags: java

How to implement heart beat mechanism, to find out the connection between the server and client using servlets?

Comment: That isn't called a handshake -- but a "heartbeat" rather

Comment: You can't.  Servlets speak HTTP, and HTTP doesn't have a heartbeat. The connection is expressed by the fact that you're inside a `doPost(),` `doGet()`, etc method.The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 The question DOES MAKE SENSE despite the HTTP protocol not forcing browsers to support this feature naturally. One could use a long polling javascript heart beat issued by the browser to the servlet at say a 5 min interval OR even use a framework like Comet to achieve the same result.